# How do I hide columns using rubyXL 3.4.0 or later?

Tags: ruby, rubyxl

How do I hide columns using rubyXL 3.4.0 or later?

The example here (https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL/issues/145) appears to be out-of-date. (`sheet.cols.find` now returns an `Enumerator`, so doesn't have a `hidden` method.)

Code from rubyXL issue #145:

```
# Assuming that the cells/rows/cols are respectively locked in the test file:
doc = RubyXL::Parser.parse('test.xlsx')
sheet = doc.worksheets[0]
sheet.sheet_data.rows[0].hidden
=> nil
sheet.sheet_data.rows[1].hidden
=> true
(c = sheet.cols.find(0)) && c.hidden
=> nil
(c = sheet.cols.find(1)) && c.hidden
=> true

xf = doc.workbook.cell_xfs[c.style_index || 0]
xf.apply_protection && xf.protection.locked
=> true
xf.apply_protection && xf.protection.hidden
=> true
```

Comment: Can you please add in code blocks of the code you are using, as external sites can change at any time, and require your helper to leave this one to access the data

Answer (score 0):

> the example you offer is not to hide columns   but to get the hidden
> status of columns

**Edited to prevent misleading others**

> <strike>looks like rubyXL doesn't have feature to hide columns   its
> main purpose is to parse xlsx file   the hidden attribute is only for
> reading, you can't change it with rubyXL</strike>

**actually you can, see the solution Zack figure out**

> I found this gem, [write_xlsx](https://github.com/cxn03651/write_xlsx#readme) to have capability to hide columns /
> rows   but in contrast, it's for creating xlsx   they have
> [example](https://github.com/cxn03651/write_xlsx/blob/main/examples/hide_row_col.rb) in the github repo about how to hide   I didn't find any
> other gem that can achive this goal easily(hide specific columns from
> an existed xlsx file)   maybe you can
>
> 1. read the original xlsx file with rubyXL
> 2. use the data parsed from rubyXL and make a whole new xlsx file with write_xlsx gem (hide the target column in this step)
> 3. replace original xlsx file

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

The following code does generate a new workbook with column B hidden:

```
require "rubyXL"
require "rubyXL/convenience_methods"

workbook = RubyXL::Workbook.new
sheet = workbook.worksheets.first

sheet.add_cell(0,0, "Sam")
sheet.add_cell(0,1, "George")
sheet.add_cell(0,2, "John")

sheet.cols.get_range(1).hidden = true

workbook.write('hide_b.xlsx')
```

(I also put a copy of this code here: https://github.com/kurmasz/rubyXL-recipes)